# Why was my post downvoted?

Tags: support

Why was my answer downvoted? Was there an error in what I posted?

[See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701323/executable-files/701346#701346).

Edit: I have edited my original post to answer his question.

***Lesson learned.  Always read the question carefully to ensure the proper answer is given.***

PS: Apologies for being ignorant in the ways of Meta.

Comment: It just happens to be me that downvoted your answer. The reason is that it doesn't appear to answer the question. You are making the assumption that the OP wants to run an .exe file but this wasn't said and the question implies they *can't* find an executable file. This is just my interpretation of the question and the answer; people can downvote for whichever reason they choose and are not usually required to give their reasoning, but I'm happy to do so here voluntarily.

Comment: Just found out how to comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Meta is ***not*** an inappropriate place to ask this sort of stuff. I wish other people asked this sort of thing rather than blindly carrying on.

Comment: @thomasrutter assumption that the OP made isn't that bad - we should expect people coming form the Windows world.

Comment: @Serg have a look at the question in the link and read through - if we expect OP to have come from the Windows world, and he's saying he can't find an executable, then it means he probably **doesn't** have a .exe.  I did indeed read the question and answer with due consideration.  At any rate, downvotes don't have to be justified.

Comment: @Oli this has been moved to meta.  It was in askubuntu.com.

Comment: The downvotes don't have to be justified, true, but it sure is better to leave a comment. A user should have feedback to adjust one's behavior accordingly. I got as far as i have only thanks to people willing to communicate with me and guide , instead of plain downvoting

Comment: I am actually unable to comment until my rep has increased.  I am able to comment here, but not in the the normal askubuntu.

Comment: @Serg I agree that would be a good principle.  For me, if the person who wrote the answer asks why they were downvoted I usually am happy to explain (as in this case), but I otherwise don't always leave a comment.

Comment: @Cyndekai you can always comment on your own answers regardless of rep, as far as I understand (if this isn't the case, someone correct me).  If you can't comment on that answer anymore it'll be because you deleted the answer.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -5):

Because your answer is not useful,
 You can edit your first answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more useful.  I didn't originally understand his full question, because he asked multiple questions.  I simply answered how to install the .exe instead of explaining how to find a .exe in a .zip.  Alas, it has been edited, and now fully answers his question.

Comment: "Because your answer is not useful" and neither is this one, how about some details on why it is "not useful" for the OP ?